# Get rid of multiple one-to-one relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, dependencies, relationship, one-to-one

I have multiple one-to-one relationships in the following data model between:

- logins & accounts
- donors & accounts
- patients & accounts

[SQL Server Blood Bank data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGPm8.png)

I am facing troubles in altering the database, mainly caused by **FK's** related to *one-to-one relationships*, made only between **PK'S**.

My best guess is that all my troubles are caused by **a bad design**. How can I get rid of the one-to-one dependencies?

Any changes could be made..

Comment: The design doesn't seem wrong or bad to me. Rather very right and good. It seems like `accounts` models a weak entity (which makes sense). PK and FK are meant to be the same there.

Comment: seems right to me as well, what exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: I feel that there's a too a high coupling due to accounts table bounded to 3 different tables using one-to-one relationship. When I try to insert a new row, in patients table, for example, and there is **NOT** already an account with **exactly** the same index on **PK**, then i get _No row was updated. Error Message: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKpatientsaccounts"._

Comment: All PK from tables involved in one-to-one dependencies are set on auto increment. I cannot avoid situations in which two **different** PK's values are connected by a one-to-one dependency. Let's say a donor is created, with donor_id = 3. An account will be generated having accound_id=3. Now, if i want to add a patient that has patient_id = 3, that account id is already taken.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think its so better than your database design.
Do you have any question?